# How to solve this non-linear differential equation, using separation of variables?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation

$$\frac{d}{dt}(V_1) = -k\cdot\left(\frac{1}{V_1^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{(V_{tot}-V_1)^{1/3}}\right)$$

Here $k$ and $V_{tot}$ are positive constants. Describes the volume of a soap-bubble when connected to another soap-bubble.

I have tried doing separation of variables but I get a rather ugly integral, for $V_1$.
$$\int \frac{(V_1 V_{tot} -V_1^2)^{1/3}}{(V_{tot}-V_1)^{1/3}-V_1^{1/3}}dV_1$$

How do I solve this differential equation/integral? Are there any substitution/techniques I can use?

Comment: There is the constant solution $V(t) = \frac{V_{tot}}{2}$

Comment: That is true, but that solution is not that interesting, but none the less a solution

Comment: This integral can be expressed in terms of combination of hypergeometric and Appellhypergeometric functions. This is too ugly to be usable for applications. For practical use better proceed with direct numerical integration.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about thoose functions, but I why they are not pratical. Thanks for the answer tho!